# Firefox/Chrome JSON parsing numeric value in JSON as numeric value -1 for 1 specific value

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, firefox, integer

The following json with an integer in Firefox:

```
{"inventoryIds":15369683015733721}
```

parses the numeric value as `15369683015733720`

This behavior has not been observed in other numeric values (so far).

To replicate: Save the json on disk and load in Firefox. The displayed value then looks like:

```
inventoryIds:   15369683015733720
```

Work around has been applied by just parsing the data as a string, which solves the issue, but the root cause would be nice to know.

(Same issue occurs in Chrome, tested on Linux (openSuse Leap, and Ubuntu 18.04LTS))

Comment: Javascript stores numbers inside of 64bits, not every number fits into that.

Comment: Your number is about 1.53e+16. The maximum safe integer value (number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) for javascript is  9007199254740991 (about 9e+15). So you're running out of large-numbers luck in javascript. Since it's an ID, its probably pretty safe to handle it as a string.

Comment: @Jonas I got to 9223372036854775807 for a signed 64bit. This is 1e3 larger than my value. However it turns out as indicated in the duplicate that the limit is a paltry 52bits.

Comment: @norbert jup, only 52bit of those 64bit can be used as integer, the rest is the exponent